# How to apply same data manipulation codes to a group of SSIS components' inputs?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS.

I have a number of MS access tables to transform to SQL. Some of these tables have datetime fields needed to go under some rules before sitting in respected SQL tables. I want to use Script component that deals with these kind of fields converting them to the desired values.
Since all of these fields need same modification rules, I want to apply the same code base to all of them thus avoiding the code duplication. What would be the best option for this scenario?

I know I can't use the same Script Component and direct all of those datasets outputs to it because unfortunately it doesn't support multi-inputs . So the question is is it possible to apply a set of generic data manipulation rules
on a group of different datasets' fields without repeating the rules. I can use a Script component for each ole db input and apply the same rule on them each. But it would not be an efficient way of doing that.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Integration Services has a [specific task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140321.aspx) to suit this need, called a [Data Conversion Transformation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I9IfZUK2dk) This can be accomplished on the data source or via the task, [as noted here](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-data-type-conversion-options-in-ssis/).

You can also use the [Derived Column transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_nAa-lXCcE) to convert data. This transformation is also simple, select an input column and then chose whether to replace this column or create a new output column. Then you apply an expression for the output column.

So why use one over the other?

The [Data Conversion transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-erJpymyyM) (Pictured Below) will take an input, convert the type and provide a new output column. If you use the Derived Column transformation, you get to apply an expression to the data, which allows you to do more complex manipulations on the data.

[image: SSIS Data Conversion Task]

Comment: Thanks @Bryan for the answer. But as I mentioned I need to apply some rather complicated rules into the datetime field values for which I think I'd better do some coding or scripting. It is not just a simple type casting.Plus I need to do this on a high number of columns across multiple tables preferably in a generic way . I found DataConversion too simple to do the job for me, Also the Derived columns needed to be repeated for all of the columns across all the tables. Having said that, Can I use the Script component or any other in an efficient way to get the job done?